# Setting up Symfony 3 with NetBeans 8

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans-8

I am not able to setup Symfony 3.0 with NetBeans 8.

Here is what I have done:

```
NetBeans IDE: Tools -> Options -> PHP -> Framework & Tools -> Symfony 2/3 -> symfony2/3
```

In the installer textbox, I gave the path to the `symfony.zip` file.

When I create a new PHP project with the Symfony framework, I get the following error:

[image]

I am not able to begin with the Symfony project.